# On refresh not getting `router events`

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular8

I am doing a breadcrumb for my project. I have two issues here:

1. When I come from its sibling page, breadcrumb not generated
2. When page refreshed the breadcrumb not generated

How to solve both of them?

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RoutesRecognized, NavigationStart,  NavigationEnd, Params, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BreadCrumbsService } from './../../services/bread-crumbs.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'bread-crumbs',
    templateUrl: './bread-crumbs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bread-crumbs.component.scss']
})
export class BreadCrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

    breadcrumbList: Array<any> = [];

    /**
        * Setting Breadcrumb object, where name for display, path for url match,
        link for heref value, getting datas from BreadCrumbsService service
    */

    constructor(private router: Router, private bCService: BreadCrumbsService) {

        this.generateBreadCrumb();

    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    generateBreadCrumb() {

        console.log('hi');

        let routerUrl: string, routerList: Array<any>, target: any;

        this.router.events.subscribe((router: any) => {

            console.log('do'); //not consoles on above 2 points

            routerUrl = router.urlAfterRedirects;


        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `generateBreadCrumb` in `ngOnInit` instead of `constructor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Router subscription-logic i´m using is even more restrictive and works:

```html
constructor(private router: Router) { 
     router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                console.log(event.urlAfterRedirects);
            }
          });
}
```

So i think your issue is caused by the way you set up your router module.
Did you test wether your router works by using two components in two URLS?
Or would you share your router module with us?

Answer (score 2):

The above solution was not working for me. I came out with the following solution

```
export BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
        
isRefreshed = true; // dummy variable flag
   
     constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public breadcrumbService: FinlexBreadcrumbService) {
       this.router.events
         .pipe(
           filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
           distinctUntilChanged()
         )
         .subscribe(() => {
           //Build your breadcrumb starting with the root route of your current activated route. will call only on navigation change
           this.isRefreshed = false;
           this.breadcrumbService.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.firstChild);
         });
     }
   
     ngOnInit(): void {
       if (this.isRefreshed) {
//will call only when page reload happens          
this.breadcrumbService.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.firstChild);
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: this works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I added another type of event to the condition and it solved me the problem:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { 
   router.events
        .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof Scroll))
        .subscribe((val: any) => {
          console.log(val.url || val.routerEvent.url);
        })
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, though I found that it fires twice on regular navigation.  I found instead to only use Scroll worked for me:

.pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof Scroll))

Your answer should be the preferred answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

might be because your component rendered later then a root component, better to create a service and init route watch service method from a root component